# cascade delete sequence delete(want to know which table row in cascade delete is deleted first)

Tags: mysql

T1:

```
IDT1        NAME      AGE    
  1          RAM      20    
  2          SAM      21    
  3          JAM      22
```

(IDT1 IS PK TO TABLE T1 AND FOREIGN KEY TO T2 AND T3 WITH CASCADE DELETE ON)

T2:

```
ID    NAME   GEN   IDT1       
 1      AB      M      1    
 2      CD      M      2
```

T3:

```
ID   NAME     PLACE   IDT1       
1      LL        KOL      1    
2      MM        LOK      2
```

**Question**: If I delete IDT1=2 from T1, then IDT1=2 from T2 and T3 will be also deleted as per cascade delete..But i want to know which row (T2 OR T3 'S IDT1=2) would be deleted first..

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: i just want to know the sequence of deletion

Comment: Then create an on delete trigger on both t2 and t3 and log the deletion into a table. But I would not be surprised if the order of the deletion would change time to time. MySQL documentation does not specify the order of the deletion and it does not seem to be an issue either.

Comment: I also tried but could not find the sequence

Comment: @Shadow ["Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel oh, I forgot about that, thanks for the reminder. In this case, I do not think there is any way to determine the order. But, again, the order does not matter.

Comment: You can try to create table `T2a` with FK to `T2` and `T3a` with FK to `T3`. Both with `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. Then see what error you get trying to delete from T1.